# XMPPFramework - TURNSocket can't receive the data that sent by myself?

Tags: ios, xmpp, file-transfer, xmppframework

I used the openfire as the xmpp server, and want to transfer file via the Turnsocket.

The openfire (local) config:

```
xmpp.auth.anonymous                true
xmpp.domain                        local
xmpp.enabled                       true
xmpp.externalip                    proxy.local, 192.168.1.101, 127.0.0.1
xmpp.proxy.enabled                 true
xmpp.proxy.port                    7777
xmpp.proxy.transfer.required       false
xmpp.server.socket.active          true
xmpp.session.conflict.limit        0
xmpp.socket.ssl.active             true
```

I tested the file transfer in the local environment,  one user is logged in by Simulator (Sender), the other user is logged in by Device (iPod, receiver).

1. TURNSocket.m (both changed), change the proxy

   ```
   + (void)initialize {
       ...
       proxyCandidates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"local", nil];
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Config both on sender and receiver

   ```
   - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {

       ...

       if ([TURNSocket isNewStartTURNRequest:iq]) {

           NSLog(@"IS NEW TURN request Receive.. TURNSocket..................");

           TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:xmppStream incomingTURNRequest:iq];
           [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
           [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
           [turnSocket release];
       }
       return YES;
   }
   ```
3. Setup and call TURNSocket (Sender)

   ```
   TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:user.primaryResource.jid];
   [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
   [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   [turnSocket release];
   ```
4. didSucceed called both (sender and receiver)

   ```
   - (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {
   ```

   }
5. Send a file? on sender

   ```
   - (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

       NSData *dataF = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a1" ofType:@"png"]];

       [socket writeData:dataF withTimeout:60.0f tag:0];
   }
   ```

   OR: Received data here? (Receiver)

   ```
   - (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {

       NSData *dataF = [[NSData alloc] init];

       [socket readDataToData:dataF withTimeout:30.0 tag:0];
       NSLog(@"dataF: %d", [dataF length]); //  dataF: 0
   }
   ```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Neil. Did you make any progress here?

Comment: how did you transferred the file ?

Comment: Please let me know if done any progress on sending files

Comment: Neil, is didSucceed getting called for you? If yes, could please let me know how you did that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

To set an external ip address, you need to use xmpp.proxy.externalip rather than xmpp.externalip