# Enabling mod_proxy65 on ejabberd server installed on ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: iphone, ios, proxy, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on a iOS chat application, so for media transfer to work i need to enable mod_proxy65, and i have enabled the same in ejabberd.cfg file with their default setting: `{mod_proxy65[]}`. on client side i am using the https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework xmpp framework for iOS. 
in TURNSocket.m i have used proxy candidate as `dev.myserver.com` in place of default `jabber.org` . now when I try to open the TURN connection, the series of iq received and sent are as follows:

SEND: `<iq type="get" to="dev.myserver.com" id="A9876DD0-B13C-4DC7-B812-2A6E653288BC"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>`

RECV: `<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="dev.gungroo.com" to="smita@dev.myserver.com/24983171131368877324197828" id="A9876DD0-B13C-4DC7-B812-2A6E653288BC" type="result"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="conference.dev.myserver.com"/><item jid="irc.dev.myserver.com"/><item jid="proxy.dev.myserver.com"/><item jid="pubsub.dev.myserver.com"/><item jid="vjud.dev.myserver.com"/></query></iq>`

SEND: `<iq type="get" to="proxy.dev.myserver.com" id="26D694FB-C679-478C-A3D1-A84B9A583534"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>`

RECV: `<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="proxy.dev.myserver.com" to="smita@dev.myserver.com/24983171131368877324197828" id="26D694FB-C679-478C-A3D1-A84B9A583534" type="result"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" type="bytestreams" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="vcard-temp"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="result"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo</value></field></x></query></iq>`

SEND: `<iq type="get" to="proxy.dev.myserver.com" id="C60068A2-985C-4C5C-87B3-C9FFFB41FDF0"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>`

RECV: `<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="proxy.dev.gungroo.com" to="smita@dev.myserver.com/24983171131368877324197828" id="C60068A2-985C-4C5C-87B3-C9FFFB41FDF0" type="result"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.dev.myserver.com" host="10.212.103.159" port="7777"/></query></iq>`

here is the problem, its returning me the internal ip address(10.212.103.159) of server dev.myserver.com, resulting in failure of making the TURN connection. why doesn't it return external ip address of proxy.dev.myserver.com ? 
to be on the same page: proxy.dev.myserver.com and dev.myserver.com both points to same external ip. and the port 7777 is open at my server dev.myserver.com . anybody who have worked with the same, please help??
here is the last iq(sent and received) which shows the error message:

SEND

```
<iq type="set" to="smita1@dev.myserver.com/38303823331368691199448799" id="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240" mode="tcp">
        <streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.dev.myserver.com" host="10.212.103.159" port="7777"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

RECV

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="smita1@dev.myserver.com/38303823331368691199448799" to="smita@dev.myserver.com/278621573136869119737843" type="error" id="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240" mode="tcp">
       <streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.dev.myserver.com" host="10.212.103.159" port="7777"/>
    </query>
    <error type="cancel" code="501">
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

it would be really great if someone can point me to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you are not accessing from outside your internal network?

Comment: though too late, uncomment this `##mod_proxy65: {}` from `jabbed.yml` file and make it like `mod_proxy65: {
    host: "proxy.@HOST@"
  }`

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to resolve the issue. xx.xx.xx.xx is my external ip:
  {mod_proxy65,  [{hostname, ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]}]},

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this setting in the new YML config format that Ejabberd now uses?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this ,I can give an idea [[XMPPFramework - TURNSocket can't receive the data that sent by myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877864/turnsocket-cant-receive-the-data-that-sent-by-myself?rq=1) ]

Also [http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html],[ [XMPP Sending/Receving file in iphone sdk ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328553/xmpp-sending-receving-file-in-iphone-sdk?rq=1) ]

Comment: hey,first i had already seen these two links but didn't help. in ejabberd conig i dont find any setting like xmpp.externalip as they have mentioned for openfire, and when i try to enable the mod_proxy with ip setting like {mod_proxy65[{ip,{xx,xx,xx,xx}}]}, where xx.xx.xx.xx is external ip of my server where ejabberd is installed, then server refuse to restart with error, ip already taken. also i am using xep-0065, xep-0096 is just for file transfer not other medias.